# Ajax form submission issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a simple form that I am trying to submit via ajax. I load in Jquery and got this simple form:

```
<form id="post_edit">
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="1">
<input type="text" id="title" name"title" value="This is the title">
<textarea id="body" name="body" rows="3">This is the body</textarea>
<button type="submit" onclick="this.form.submit();" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
```

Then I have this code to submit the form via ajax:

```
$("#post_edit").submit(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault(); 

            var form = $(this);
            var url = 'http://localhost/ajax/posts/' + form.attr('id');

            $.ajax({
                type: "PATCH",
                url: url,
                data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                success: function(data)
                {
                    toastr.success('The post was successfully updated!')
                },
                error:function() {
                    toastr.error('Unable to save changes to the post.<br />Please try again later.')
                }
            });

        });
```

Idk why but the ajax submission isn't working, instead is just POSTs to the current URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onclick` attribute of the `submit` button you're triggering the form submission on the `form` Element. This will not be caught by jQuery, and causes the behaviour you're seeing whereby the form submit. As it has no `action` specified it sends a POST request, by default as again there's no `method` attribute, to the current URL.

To fix this issue you simply need to remove the `onclick` attribute from the HTML and rely solely on the unobtrusive event handler you've attached using jQuery:

```html
<button type="submit" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
```

Comment: Odd because I had to add the onclick to get the form to do anything. I originally didn't have it but there was no submission made. The network tab in developer tools showed no request being made at all when I clicked submit, it just closed the modal and did nothing further.

Comment: In that case you perhaps need to wrap your jQuery code in a document.ready event handler to ensure that it's executed after the DOM has loaded.

Comment: So that didn't work either. I had to do that and change my function to target the onclick event for the submit button using it's id. Now its working.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.